# Regex to not allow special character without prefix or suffix

Tags: javascript, regex

I was writing regex for the following validate a string. I wrote the following regex.

```
^[^\s]+[a-z]{0,}(?!.* {2})[ a-zA-z]{0,}$
```

it validates for

1. No space in beginning.
2. no two consecutive space allowed.
3. The problem is it allows a single special character. it should not allow a special character unless it is suffixed or prefixed with alpha-numeric character.

Examples:

`#` -> not allowed.

`#A` or `A#` or `A2` or `3A` is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to assert that the string does not contain a single "special" char or 2 special chars next to each other using a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s][^a-zA-Z0-9\s])(?!.*(?:^| )[^a-zA-Z0-9\s](?!\S))\S+(?: \S+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what is at the right does not contain

  - `.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s][^a-zA-Z0-9\s]` match 2 chars other than a-zA-Z0-9 or a whitespace char next to each other
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what is at the right does not contain

  - `.*(?:^| )[^a-zA-Z0-9\s](?!\S)` Match a single char other than  a-zA-Z0-9 or a whitespace char
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\S+(?: \S+)*` Match 1+ non whitespace chars and optionally repeat a space and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWLfcg/1)

Comment: this looks good. but now my problem is that this is not able to validate 2 special characters together. eg.  ##A, A## is valid.

Comment: @vijaysingh Can you give an example what you do and do not want to match in that case?

Comment: #  alone or ## is not valid but #A  or ##A  is valid. likewise.

Comment: @vijaysingh Do you mean like this? `^(?!.*(?:^| )[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?!\S))\S+(?: \S+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/RtuIFF/1

Answer (score 1):

Please omit the '$' symbol from the regex because it represents the end of the sentence.

```
^[^\s]+[a-z]{0,}(?!.* {2})[ a-zA-z]{0,}
```

So when applying the above regex to the following, it finds only '# '.

> ## #A A# A2 3A

Comment: it doesn't validate with single special character. eg: #  is valid. it should not be.